# How to count total record inside foreach using php?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem to count total record inside foreach using php.

My code is here

```
$User_Line=@mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("select * from tb_user where user_login_id='$_SESSION[SEEKER_ID]'"));
$userskill=explode(",",$User_Line['user_skills_id']);
foreach($userskill as $skill) 
{
   $tb_job=mysql_query("select * from tb_job where job_keyskills like '%$skill%'");
   $tb_job2=mysql_fetch_array($tb_job);
   echo "TOTAL=".$value=mysql_num_rows($tb_job);
}
```

Current result is coming like `TOTAL=12 TOTAL=4 TOTAL=0` 
But It should be like `TOTAL = 16`

Please help me

Comment: [Why shouldn't I use mysql_* functions in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

Did you just try to sum each values in a variable?

```
$User_Line=@mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("select * from tb_user where user_login_id='$_SESSION[SEEKER_ID]'"));
$userskill=explode(",",$User_Line['user_skills_id']);
$total = 0;
foreach($userskill as $skill) 
{    
    $tb_job=mysql_query("select * from tb_job where job_keyskills like '%$skill%'");
    $tb_job2=mysql_fetch_array($tb_job);
    $total +=  mysql_num_rows($tb_job);        
}
echo "TOTAL=".$total;
```

Comment: @user3523177 if it did helped you and solved the problem kindly upvote or accept this answer to repay the answerers effort. good day :)

Answer (score 0):

Outside your loop define the variable `$total`

```
$total = 0;

foreach($userskill as $skill) 
{
...
$total = $total + $value=mysql_num_rows($tb_job); // add the $value to $total
}

echo $total;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$User_Line=@mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("select * from tb_user where user_login_id='$_SESSION[SEEKER_ID]'"));
$userskill=explode(",",$User_Line['user_skills_id']);

$Total=0;

foreach($userskill as $skill) 
{
   $tb_job=mysql_query("select * from tb_job where job_keyskills like '%$skill%'");
   $tb_job2=mysql_fetch_array($tb_job);
   $value=mysql_num_rows($tb_job);
   $Total=$Total+$Value;
}
echo "TOTAL=".$Total;
```